# Capture or modify Laravel's error pages?

Tags: php, laravel, livereload, whoops

I'd like to insert a code snippet into Laravel's error pages, but I can't figure out how to modify or capture the output.

This filthy hack seems to work, but the snippet is inserted before any page code.

```php
// In laravel/app/start/global.php

App::error(function (Exception, $exception, $code)
{
    echo '<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error pages are in resources/views/errors. You can then simply add whatever you want inside those file by naming them with the status code like `503.blade.php`.

You can even make a base error page and the other view extends this one.

You can also take a look at the `\App\Exceptions\Handler` class in the `report` method, you can check Exceptions that have been thrown there.